# XSL sort functionality

Tags: xslt, sorting, xpath

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
  select="$tempPosterItemNodeSet/CurrentPosterItemCollection/PosterItem" 
  mode="PosterItem">

    <xsl:sort 
      select="$tempPosterItemNodeSet/CurrentPosterItemCollection/PosterItem/Property[@name='WidgetID']" 
      data-type="number"/>

</xsl:apply-templates>
```

I need to xslt sort a nodeset that I am passing to a template in the sample I have put above.

Can anybody let me know How I can sort the above xsl logic ??

Comment: XSL Tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_sort.asp

Answer (score 1):

I think this could work:

```
<xsl:apply-templates  
  select="$tempPosterItemNodeSet/CurrentPosterItemCollection/PosterItem"  
  mode="PosterItem"> 

    <xsl:sort  
      select="Property[@name='WidgetID']"  
      data-type="number"/> 

</xsl:apply-templates>
```

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#sorting

> For each node to be processed, the
>   expression is evaluated with that node
>   as the current node and with the
>   complete list of nodes being processed
>   in unsorted order as the current node
>   list.